# Need Help in reading an XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

hi
i want to read the below file using php. the file is of very big size (in GBs). Please help me out as i dont knw much about this.

Here is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Articles>
        <Article>
            <header>info about article  </header>

        <metadata>


                    <dc:title>title here</dc:title>
                    <dc:author>author 1</dc:author>
                    <dc:author>author 2</dc:author>
                    <dc:author>author 3</dc:author>
                    <dc:author>author n</dc:author>

                    <dc:subject>subject here</dc:subject>


            </metadata>
        </Article>

        <resume> resume infor </resume>
        </Articles>
```

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem you are having, please?  Are you running out of memory?  Is the parser barfing?

Comment: the main problem is while using simple DOM parser the program stops automatically after some time...2ndly the DOM program only reads the <Record> and when <resume> resume infor </resume> comes it stops again. i just want to read this file anyway possible. please help me out. i will be obliged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is that large youll probably need to use [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) to avoid running out of memory as opposed to SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

```
www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_xml_simplexml.asp
```

Try reading this page. Its of great help.

**Update** Found this snippet on StackOverflow.com's posts:

```
<?php

class SimpleDMOZParser
{
    protected $_stack = array();
    protected $_file = "";
    protected $_parser = null;

    protected $_currentId = "";
    protected $_current = "";

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->_file = $file;

        $this->_parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8");
        xml_set_object($this->_parser, $this);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->_parser, "startTag", "endTag");
    }

    public function startTag($parser, $name, $attribs)
    {
        array_push($this->_stack, $this->_current);

        if ($name == "TOPIC" && count($attribs)) {
            $this->_currentId = $attribs["R:ID"];
        }

        if ($name == "LINK" && strpos($this->_currentId, "Top/Home/Consumer_Information/Electronics/") === 0) {
            echo $attribs["R:RESOURCE"] . "\n";
        }

        $this->_current = $name;
    }

    public function endTag($parser, $name)
    {
        $this->_current = array_pop($this->_stack);
    }

    public function parse()
    {
        $fh = fopen($this->_file, "r");
        if (!$fh) {
            die("Epic fail!\n");
        }

        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $data = fread($fh, 4096);
            xml_parse($this->_parser, $data, feof($fh));
        }
    }
}

$parser = new SimpleDMOZParser("content.rdf.u8");
$parser->parse();
```

Comment: No, no it isn't.  [w3schools teaches poor coding practices](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: It still won't help with this specific case.  The OP's XML file is multiple gigabytes in size.  SimpleXML loads the entire file, then converts it into a PHP data structure.  This will take *at least* the same amount of memory as the size of the file, possibly double that, and probably more.  SimpleXML is great for *simple* XML.  This ain't simple.  :)

Comment: @ charles
u r right. i m facing the same memory issue. 2ndly when <resume> resume infor </resume> tag comes in <record> the program stops.. using simple DOM parser. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

good place to start is [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) from PHP